# How can I update Vim's dynamic SQL completion when the database changes?

Tags: sql, vim

I am using Vim's dynamic SQL completion and the dbext plugin which provides completion of tables and columns etc by using a live connection  to a database.
e.g. if I type (while in insert mode)`<C-c>t` a popup list of tables will appear.
However if the database schema changes - which of course it does when I'm developing it - the plugin doesn't update its local cache of the database schema.
The docs say this:

> The SQL completion plugin caches various lists that are displayed in
>   the popup window.  This makes the re-displaying of these lists very
>   fast.  If new tables or columns are added to the database it may
>   become necessary to clear the plugins cache.  The default map for this
>   is:
>   `imap <buffer> <C-C>R <C-\><C-O>:call sqlcomplete#Map('ResetCache')<CR><C-X><C-O>`

However when I run the above command `<C-c>R` or `<C-\><C-O>` or any combination all vim displays is a message that items from the cache have been removed.
But when I use the completion, its still based on the old schema.
I have also tried pasting

```
:call sqlcomplete#Map('ResetCache')<CR><C-X><C-O>
```

directly into the command line, but that doesnt work either.
.
Is there any way I get this cache to update so the completion plugin is based on a current version of the database?
Or even just turn the caching off?

Comment: Have you reported this to the plugin's author?

Comment: no, I wasnt sure how ?  it doesnt seem like the github repo is active

Comment: Many old plugins are so stable, there's little activity. Just give it a try!

Comment: ok, yes I agree about the fact that it appears the plugin may  actually have a bug.  I ran the code through vims debugger trying to find the logic that deals it, in case the order of script execution was the source of the problem. I could find the exact logic but it does seem possible the plugin may have a bug, so yes Ill look at notifying the author